# IE 11 - sessionStorage not being removed or cleared for new tabs or windows

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular5, internet-explorer-11

I am using the sessionStorage objects in the angular project to save some data for processing. Somehow it is behaving very weird in the IE 11 browser.

```
  sessionStorage.setItem('data-x', '1000');
```

When i open the new tab or window from the existing application page and uses the same URL or different URL from the application, it also shares the sessionStorage data. And that is what i was not expecting... **For new tabs|windows, it must remove the existing sessionStorage data and have the slate clean**. But it is not doing that in IE 11.

In Chrome, when the user opens up the new tab or window from the existing app page, it does not share the sessionStorage objects.

Comment: Is there a way we resolve this issue in IE ?

Comment: Which exact version of IE 11 and which OS you are using for testing? I suggest you to check for a latest updates. If any updates are available then install it and check whether it solves the issue or not.

Comment: I am using IE - 11.0.90 and OS - Windows 10.

Comment: I had made the test on my side and I am able to produce the issue on my side. Currently no any solution or work around available for this issue. I will try to inform the MSFT developers about this issue via internal Chanel. To avoid the issue you can try to use MS Edge. It is working properly with SessionStorage.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT This issue is even present in MS Edge also.

Comment: In the image, You can see my testing result with MS Edge and it looks like it is working properly. https://i.postimg.cc/9QSdSq7T/40.gif you can try to post your testing result. It may help us to understand the issue in better way.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do the trick for me in IE11 on Windows 10:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", function (changes) {
    //workaround for IE11 storage synchronization problem.
    //Leave this in place, empty or not

    // Optionally do something
    //if (changes["key"] == "data-x") { //Do something; }
});
```

Modified from the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42377129/4805434

Old question, but I've just spent WAY too much time trying to get localStorage to sync up between tabs in IE11. This solution appears to help with clearing out sessionStorage for new tabs and windows as well.