# Word add-in dialog not reflecting the localstorage value set from parent

Tags: ms-word, office-js, add-in

I'm using office dialog api in word add-in. when I set a localstorage & read in the dialog after it opens, I see the value in the dialog. But when the dialog is open & I set the localstorage in parent, I do not see that showing up in the dialog. I'm using localstorage for communication to child dialog after launch. 
Is there any other way of communicating between parent & child after the dialog is open? using Office.context.ui.messageParent when sending message from dialog to parent.

```
Main page:

$scope.opensettingDialog = function () {
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost/tz/setting", {90,50},
               function (asyncResult) {
                   dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processSettingDialog);
        });}

function processSettingDialog (arg) {
    var messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    if (messageFromDialog.messageType == "save") {
        //do operations & store result
        localStorage.setItem("tbSave", "true");
    }
    else {
        dialog.close();
    }
}


Settings Dialog:

$scope.acceptSettings = function () {

    var messageObject = {
        messageType: "savedoc"
    };
    var jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(messageObject);
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(jsonMessage);

    $scope.intervalpromise = $interval(checkSave2Update(), 1000);


};

//Wait for parent operation to complete
var checkSave2Update= function () {
    var processingStatus = localStorage.getItem("tbSave");//it never has the value set in the parent page.

    if ((processingStatus == "undefined") || (processingStatus == null)) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.intervalpromise);
        $scope.intervalpromise = $interval(checkSave2Update(), 1000);
        return;
    }
    else {//cancel wait
        $interval.cancel($scope.intervalpromise);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please add some code snippet to help people to answer, and please read the: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, to better understand how to construct a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of localStorage, it might just be that you're running into an Internet Explorer issue (on the desktop, Office Add-in run inside of an IE container).

The issue and workaround are described in detail in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40770399.  Basically, local storage may get out of sync across tabs (and that's effectively what a taskpane vs. dialog are).  To fix this, you can set a value on some key, and this will ensure that localStorage is refreshed.

We use this workaround in Script Lab:  see https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/packages/common/src/utilities/ensure.fresh.local.storage.ts

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Michael. After adding an empty local storage item(localStorage.setItem("tbtest", null);), local Storage is refreshed and synched up.